# Buy 1 Sku, get 2 for a fixed amount

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, sku

I need to create a rule that states:
Buy 1 product sku at full price and get 2 product skus for fixed discounted amounts.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento promotions are somewhat limited with respect to Buy X and get Y free.  I found this and it looks like it may support your request - https://amasty.com/special-promotions.html

Please note that I am NOT affiliated with Amasty....just trying to help.